# Get messageID from botsent embed

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get the ID of the embed-message which was sent by my bot.
I tried `msgID = await client.get_message(channel, message_id)`
and `msgID = message.id`
Both do not work and I think I understand why. But I still need the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign when sending it

```py
message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

To get the ID simply do `message.id`

```py
msgID = message.id
```

Comment: What is that ctx thing? / How do I use it / Do I have to rearrange my whole code to use it?

Comment: You didn't provide any code at all, how am I supposed to know what are you using? Instead of `ctx` you can use anything that's messageable, in the `on_message` event it'd look like this `message = await message.channel.send('whatever')`, next time ask a better question and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)